# Image in nav won't resize

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to html, and I'm having an issue resizing an image. I'm using html5 and css3. I want to put a logo in the right side of the navbar, but every time I resize it, it stays its original size.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.navlink:link, .navlink:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlink:hover, .navlink:active {
  background-color: rgb(162, 2, 2);
}

.navlink:first-letter {
  font-size: 250% ;
}
nav {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin:auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-bottom: white thin solid;
  z-index: 1000;
  clear: both;
}

#ucc_logo{
  float:right;
  height: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <a href="index.html" class="navlink"><li>Base</li></a>
    <a href="output.html" class="navlink"><li>Output</li></a>
    <a href="obscure.html" class="navlink"><li>Obscure</li></a>
    <a href="logic.html" class="navlink"><li>Logic</li></a>
    <a href="extras.html" class="navlink"><li>Extras</li></a>
  </ul>
  <a id="ucc_logo" href="http://www.ucc.ie/en/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ISnWKPd.jpg" alt="UCC Logo"></a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are applying height and with to #ucc_logo which wont resize the image.

You will have to apply css to the image itself.

you ca do

```
#ucc_logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

it will make the height and width of the image equal to the parent element

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much, I was concentrating so much on figuring out why the height/width wasn't working I missed the obvious mistake

Answer (score 0):

You were sizing the wrong element.  If you want to keep the aspect ratio correct for the image, you need to apply css to it instead.

Also, since the anchor tag and image follow the UL, the float right is going to drop it to the next line rather than keep it on the first line like I assumed you wanted (could be wrong, perhaps you wanted it on the next line).

```css
nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.navlink:link, .navlink:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlink:hover, .navlink:active {
  background-color: rgb(162, 2, 2);
}

.navlink:first-letter {
  font-size: 250% ;
}
nav {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin:auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(211, 11, 11);
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-bottom: white thin solid;
  z-index: 1000;
  clear: both;
}

#ucc_logo{
  float:right;
}
#ucc_logo img {
  height: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="ucc_logo" href="http://www.ucc.ie/en/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ISnWKPd.jpg" alt="UCC Logo"></a>
  <ul>
    <a href="index.html" class="navlink"><li>Base</li></a>
    <a href="output.html" class="navlink"><li>Output</li></a>
    <a href="obscure.html" class="navlink"><li>Obscure</li></a>
    <a href="logic.html" class="navlink"><li>Logic</li></a>
    <a href="extras.html" class="navlink"><li>Extras</li></a>
  </ul>

</nav>
```